# Linear Function in Neural Network is producing large value as output

Tags: python, neural-network, regression, backpropagation

I am performing regression on the iris data set to predict its type. I have successfully performed classification using the same data and same neural network. For classification, I have used tanh as the activation function in all layers. But for regression, I am using tanh function in the hidden layer and identity function in the output layer.

```
import numpy as np

class BackPropagation:
    weight =[]
    output =[]
    layers =0
    eta = 0.1

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.layers = len(x)
        for i in range(self.layers-2):
        w = np.random.randn(x[i]+1,x[i+1]+1)
        self.weight.append(w)
        w = w = np.random.randn(x[-2]+1,x[-1])
        self.weight.append(w)

    def tanh(self,x):
        return np.tanh(x)

    def deriv_tanh(self,x):
        return 1.0-(x**2)

    def linear(self,x):
        return x

    def deriv_linear(self,x):
        return 1


    def training(self,in_data,target,epoch=100):
        bias = np.atleast_2d(np.ones(in_data.shape[0])*(-1)).T
        in_data = np.hstack((in_data,bias))
        print("Training Starts ......")

        while epoch!=0:
            epoch-=1
            self.output=[]
            self.output.append(in_data)
            # FORWARD PHASE
            for j in range(self.layers-2):
                y_in = np.dot(self.output[j],self.weight[j])
                y_out = self.tanh(y_in)
                self.output.append(y_out)

            y_in = np.dot(self.output[-1],self.weight[-1])
            y_out = self.linear(y_in)
            self.output.append(y_out)
            print("Weight Is")
            for i in self.weight:
                print(i)       

            # BACKWARD PHASE
            error = self.output[-1]-target
            print("ERROR IS")
            print(np.mean(0.5*error*error))
            delta=[]
            delta_o = error * self.deriv_linear(self.output[-1])
            delta.append(delta_o)

            for k in reversed(range(self.layers-2)):
                delta_h = np.dot(delta[-1],self.weight[k+1].T) * self.deriv_tanh(self.output[k+1])
                delta.append(delta_h)
            delta.reverse()

            # WEIGHT UPDATE

            for i in range(self.layers-1):
                self.weight[i] -= (self.eta * np.dot(self.output[i].T, delta[i]))

        print("Training complete !")
        print("ACCURACY IS")
        acc = (1.0-(0.5*error*error))*100
        print(np.mean(acc))

    def recall(self,in_data):
        in_data = np.atleast_2d(in_data)
        bias = np.atleast_2d(np.ones(in_data.shape[0])*(-1)).T
        in_data = np.hstack((in_data,bias))
        y_out = in_data.copy()
        for i in range(self.layers-2):
            y_in = np.dot(y_out,self.weight[i])
            y_out = self.tanh(y_in).copy()
        y_in = np.dot(y_out,self.weight[-1])
        y_out = self.linear(y_in).copy()
        return y_out
# MAIN
data = np.loadtxt("iris.txt",delimiter=",")
obj = BackPropagation([4,2,1])
in_data = data[:rows,:cols].copy()
target = data[:rows,cols:].copy()
obj.training(in_data,target)
print("ANSWER IS")
print(obj.recall(in_data))
```

The data set is something like this. Here, first 4 columns are features and last column contains the target value. There are 150 records like this in the data set.

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,0
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,0
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,0
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,0
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,1
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,1
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,1
5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,1
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,2
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,2
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,2
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,2
```

After every epoch, the predicted value is increasing exponentially. And, within 50 epochs, the code gives INF or -INF as output. Instead of identity function, I also tried leaky ReLU, but still the output was INF. I have also tried varying learning rate , number of neurons in hidden layers, number of hidden layers, initial weight values, number of iterations etc. 
So, how can I perform regression using neural network with back propagation of error ?

Comment: What's your loss function?

Comment: @Bastian Schoettle L = (0.5 * error * error) where error is the difference between the predicted value and the target value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mean squared error function for regression tasks. For classification tasks, one usually uses a softmax layer as output and optimizes the cross-entry cost function.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It is now generating correct output. I am just a beginner in machine learning and neural network. So, i'll definitely study about softmax and cross-entry cost function and will implement.

Comment: No worries:) We all had to start somewhere!